# System.DateTime and Caching of TimeZoneInfo and CultureInfo

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, winapi, datetime

I have two separate .NET applications, one server and another WinForms. WinForms app has a clock running showing the current Time from DateTime.Now. The Server app can change TimeZone of the box. I need to notify the WinForms app that the TimeZone has changed so that the Clock control can clear it's cache and show correct time. I can send it a message, but i am looking for a standard way how it's done in Windows. 
What's the best approach? Is registering message in both and watching for it in WndProc it?

Comment: I guess you are not calling DateTime.Now repeatedly?  If not, why not?  If you do so, wouldn't that automatically return the new local time after the time zone is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i am going to answer my own question, since it was specifically about system events and the previous answer gave a good, but generic solution. Basically, what i found out is that there is a `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` class that has a `TimeChanged` event. All you have to do in your application is do something like the following:

```
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
            TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
        };
```

This will invalidate DateTime's cache and next time you poll the time, you will have the correct time in your DateTime.Now structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are both .NET applications, I recommend using a communications technology, such as [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) to enable communication between the applications.

Your server would set up a [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) which your WinForms applications would have a proxy to the service you set up.

You would want to design your service so that your client could pass a [callback](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) so that when the time zone changes on the server, it can notify the clients.

Comment: yes, i was not complete in my question. the thing is i have 5 server apps :) that are communicating using WCF between each other, and when one of them does the TimeZone change, the others are notified. However, i was looking for a "standard" solution how it's done in general in the regard to the UI apps. it's a part of a custom shell, so some things are not working as i would have expected...

Comment: @Alex: There's no reason that you can't have the communication that happens between the servers happen between the server and clients, depending on the transport mechanism of course.